# Change font of author affiliation marker

Tags: fonts, affiliation, authblk

When using the `authblk` package I am able to adjust the font used in the author names and affiliations using the `\Authfont` and `\Affilfont` commands provided by the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Paper Title}
\author[1]{First Author}
\affil[1]{First author's affiliation}
\author[2]{Second Author} 
\author[2]{Third Author}
\affil[2]{Other authors' affiliations}
\date{}

\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\bfseries \itshape}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\mdseries \itshape}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

[image: Title generated from code]

What can I do to change the font of the marker numerals (1 and 2) to match the text they appear next to (i.e. bold-italics in the author list and italics in the affiliations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the \textsuperscript command that the package calls. And to get combined bold and italic, load the amsmath package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\bgroup
\renewcommand{\textsuperscript}[1]{$^{\boldsymbol{\mathit{#1}}}$}

\title{Paper Title}
\author[1]{First Author}
\author[2]{Second Author} 
\author[2]{Third Author}

\renewcommand{\textsuperscript}[1]{$^\mathit{#1}$}
\affil[1]{First author's affiliation}
\affil[2]{Other authors' affiliations}
\date{}
\egroup

\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\bfseries \itshape}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\mdseries \itshape}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome. So that makes the markers italicized in the authors and affiliations. Is there a way I can make the markers bold-italics in the authors list and italics in the affiliations list? I could do this by editing the two lines where `\textsuperscript` is used in my installed version of `authblk.sty`, but that doesn't seem a good approach.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The above, edited solution does this. Note that I reordered the calls of \author and \affil.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Just a note, on my machine `authblk` wouldn't correctly place commas and the word "and" in the author list unless I removed the `\bgroup` and `\egroup` commands.